# How to boot to Xubuntu with readonly mounts

Tags: boot, backup, read-only

Back when I was first using Linux (anyone remember Caldera Network Desktop?) I could boot in a readonly mode, where all drives were read-only.  If that's still possible, it's not obvious to me.

I'm working on a backup scheme using entirely OpenSource products like partclone, and I'd like to be able to include the partition I have booted from without creating anomalies.  I've tried "recovery mode" bootups, but they are still read-write.  I'm not sure that just doing a remount-ro is going to result in a consistent clean backup.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: It's certainly possible, since a Live USB, unless made persistent, normally is read-only. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal for more info on other HDD.

Comment: @DRMoishe Pippik:  Are you sure?  The live USBs I have can install upgrades, so I'm pretty sure they run RW.  But then I started from a live CD and installed Ubuntu on them, which may not make what you mean by a live USB.  Can you point me to instructions to make a RO live USB?

Comment: When an ordinary live install USB is used, it *can* write to the HDD, but you can unmount the HDD and then remount read-only.

Comment: @DRMoshe Pippik: I don't think it makes sense to unmount the root filesystem (I'm talking about when I've booted from it).  Of course I can try a mount -o remount,ro but I'm not sure what that will do with any open files, or whether it matters if that file system is ext2, ext3, or ext4.  I've been in the habit of making them all ext4, but I worry about the state of the journal if I do the remount.